# Randomly select from an array of strings in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have done some digging, and I don't believe this question has been answered yet (though I would imagine it would be simple).

I want to  select a random string from an array. For example:

```
    NSArray *strings = @[@"String1", @"String2", @"String3"];
    NSString *randomString = // how to randomly select one of the three strings in the array?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `arc4random_uniform()`:

```
NSString *randomString = strings[arc4random_uniform(strings.count)];
```

More info in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343026/45813).